# Prove that if $X^TX=X$, then $X=X^T=X^2$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

If $X^TX=X$, show that $X=X^T=X^2$.

Can someone help me with this? I'm having trouble proving this question. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: $(AB)^{T}=B^{T}A^{T}$.

Comment: where should i apply this?

Comment: What happens if you take the transpose of $X^TX=X$?

Answer (score 1):

From $X=X^TX$ it follows that $X^T=(X^TX)^T=X^T X^{TT}=X^TX.$